# [42S22][1054] Unknown column in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql

I have a statement in which works fine in PHP, but when I try it in MySQL console, I get an error:

```
sql> UPDATE users SET password = ? WHERE username = ?
(?=Test, ?=test)
[2014-03-07 17:26:31] [42S22][1054] Unknown column 'test' in 'where clause'
```

I have tried quotes around the `?`, and many other options.

It should be a simple `WHERE`, but it doesn't seem to work in console.

This makes me think it's a bad SQL request, but I can't figure out anything wrong with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to surround your string with quotes, so use

```
(?='Test', ?='test')
```

Otherwise mysql will treat them as columns which actually don't exist in your table

Comment: Worked flawless, thank you very much. I wasn't able to find a question like this, so I had to ask to better the Q/A Database.